# Сборка константного QMap в Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qt5

Потребовалось создать константный `QMap` с некоторым набором значений:

```
const QMap<QString,int> my_map{{"field1", 15000}, {"field2", 3000}};
```

На Linux с MinGW проблем нет, но VC2013 в QtCreator выдаёт ошибку `C2661`.

Как можно порешать проблему, оставив код неизменным?

**Обновление 1**

Обновление MS VS 2013 Express до последней, 4-й версии не дало положительного результата. Путём нагугливания выяснилось, что данная ошибка может быть решена только установкой компилятора VC 2015. Ну или, конечно, через использование MinGW. Поскольку переустановка компилятора, вместе с ним Qt, а также других зависимых библиотек на данный момент не целесообразно, придётся временно отказаться от использования обозначенных списков инициализации и применить решение, аналогичное в ответе @yrHeTaTeJlb.

**Обновление 2**

Забыл указать, что после обновления компилятора до 4-й версии (по идее, последней, качал с сайта майкрософта), [ошибка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn793970.aspx) сменила номер на `C2797`.

Версия [Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013)](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)

Comment: Так VS 2012 или 2013? В 2013 у меня списки инициализации работают.

Comment: @alexolut, исправлю. Стоит MS Visual Studio Express 2013, 64 бита

Comment: Помимо номера ошибки хорошо бы ещё привести текст.

Comment: К сожалению там знаки вопроса (IDE QtCreator). Поскольку сборка в виндовс имеет меньший приоритет, то не озадачился до сих пор решением вопроса кодировки.

Comment: Если использовать англоязычную версию VS, то вопросов быть не должно. Но это несколько радикальное решение.

Comment: Скоро выйдет Qt 5.8. Там уже VC2015 в требованиях, насколько я знаю, поэтому проблема конечно снимется, раз уж всё равно обновляться. Но вот почему только у меня не работает вот этот код, а у Вас в той же среде функционирует - это для меня загадка.

Comment: я про списки инициализации говорил не применимо к Qt. А в общем случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
QMap<QString, int> makeMap(){
    QMap<QString, int> result;
    result["1"] = 2;
    result["3"] = 4;
    result["5"] = 6;
    result["7"] = 8;
    result["9"] = 0;

    return result;
}

const QMap<QString, int> map = makeMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же - нужно другой компилятор под Windows. Например тот же MinGW. К примеру, взять сборку тут - [для x32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/) и/или [для x64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/), в последствии можно и [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) собрать. Им собирать быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что создавать для инициализации именованную функцию нецелесообразно. Попробуйте обойтись просто лямбдой.

```
const QMap<QString,int> map = []() {
  QMap<QString, int> result;
  result["1"] = 2;
  result["3"] = 4;
  result["5"] = 6;
  result["7"] = 8;
  result["9"] = 0;
  return result;
}();
```

Comment: Считаете, что поддержка лямб есть, а инициализации через фигурные скобки нет?

Comment: @alexolut, поддержка лямбд есть, предложенный @Majestio код собирается. Мой же код, что представлен в вопросе, - нет. В файле проекта строка `CONFIG += c++11` имеется.

Comment: @alexolut, судя по https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx - лямбды появились в более ранних версиях VS, нежели списки инициализации. Но VS я не пользовался ни разу, поэтому предположил, что возможно сработает.